# Spyder in python will not run scripts

Tags: python-2.7, spyder

I have a very bizzare problem with the spyder editor for python 2.7

I cannot run some scripts, some run, some don't.

A script of no more than:

print "test"

Does not work in spyder, but runs in a windows console.

while the same script, but written on a different machine and transferred across via dropbox runs perfectly fine.

I am sorry that I can offer no more information, but there is none.

EDITED:
screenshot added.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by " doesn't work"? can you provide the Error?

Comment: There is no error, the script doesn't run.

Comment: And what do you do to run the script?

Comment: Click the run button in spyder, a corresponding console opens( in spyder) and immediately finishes "running". No output occurs, no error, no print output.

Comment: Are you there's nothing printed in the console? I think it closes so fast that you don't have enough time to see the printed text in it.

Comment: The console is internal to the spyder IDE, it remains open after the script has "run".

Comment: Please post a screenshot of how things look in Spyder.

Comment: I Have added a screenshot after attempting to run the script.

Comment: Running the script in an interactive interpreter does work, so it's specifically the dedicated interpreter that is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many thanks to the commentors on this question, but I have found the solution and post it here for any future users.

The problem was simple, with a simple solution.

The commodo antivirus that I have been running arbitrarily changed its own settings following an update, and began blocking all new scripts from running, without telling me the user.

All I had to do to run the scripts was either disable commodo, or unblock each script.

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue started happening after I encrypted my disk due to company compliance requirements. The test program was working with python in command prompt but not in spyder. I reset the spyder environment using commands:

1. `spyder --reset`
2. `spyder --defaults`

Things started working again.